# Check if collection has length in Firestore security rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have found an answer on SO that says there is no 'official' way to check collection length via database rules, but am wondering if there is a work around that would only require a single read, besides keeping track of collection length on a document somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no workarounds other than the one you mentioned in your question.

Comment: Roger that. Thanks Doug!